# Remove a first jquery element if cookie exists

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a after x seconds display another table,so far im doing great.
I need to place 'Wait after x seconds' only once so  i need to create a cookie,and check if cookie exists  let only the the direct div.

Explained:
-First time user =you can check content after x seconds
-Repeating user=goes directly to content

Needed:ability to create a cookie,check if user is repeated=break the first div and go directly to 2nd one.
This is what i got:

```
<style>
#picOne, #picTwo {
position:absolute;
display: none;
}

#pics {
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
</style>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
/*author Philip M. 2010*/

var timeInSecs;
var ticker;

function startTimer(secs){
timeInSecs = parseInt(secs)-1;
ticker = setInterval("tick()",1000);   // every second
}

function tick() {
var secs = timeInSecs;
if (secs>0) {
timeInSecs--;
}
else {
clearInterval(ticker); // stop counting at zero
// startTimer(15);  // remove forward slashes in front of startTimer to repeat if required
}

document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = secs;
}

startTimer(15);  // 15 seconds 

</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#picOne').fadeIn(0500).delay(15000).fadeOut(000);
    $('#picTwo').delay(15000).fadeIn(1500);
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="pics">
<div  id="picOne"> Your video will begin in

<span id="countdown" style="font-weight: bold;">15</span> </div>
<div id="picTwo">//something</object>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: (document.cookie) [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie]

Comment: you might want to check out [jquery.cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Comment: @Jbird I placed <script type = "text/javascript">
if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)someCookieName\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
alert("test");
How do i make to show the timing only once?
rgds
  document.cookie = "someCookieName=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
}</script>

Comment: @Joel Sorry it took so long to get back to you; college football weekend. I added some example code to an answer below that should help.

Comment: @Jbird Totally understand,i replied to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a *simple* CookieManager object I wrote to demonstrate how you can accomplish this. There is a much more robust version of this type of thing in the (MDN document.cookie docs)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie] but this should help you get a fundamental understanding. You can/should extend this to allow for domain, path, expiration, etc.

When you first visit the page, you will see the countdown message. When the countdown completes, jquery is used to replace the contents (lines 48-51) of the `#content` div. When you refresh the page, the content will be shown immediately if the `visited` cookie exists.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>document.cookie Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"><p>Your content will be shown in <span id="countdown">15</span> seconds</p></div>
<a href="#" class="delete">Remove Cookie</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var main = new Main();
    main.init();
});

var Main = function() {
    var _this = this,
        cookieMngr = new CookieManager(),
        countInterval = false,
        count = 15;

    _this.init = function() {
        if(cookieMngr.getCookie("visited")) {
            _this.addContent();
        } else {
            countInterval = setInterval(_this.updateCountdown, 1000);
        }

        $(".delete").on("click", function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            cookieMngr.deleteCookie("visited");
            document.location = document.location;
        });
    };

    _this.updateCountdown = function() {
        if(count > 0) {
            count--;
            $("#countdown").text(count);
        } else {
            clearInterval(countInterval);
            countInterval = false;
            cookieMngr.setCookie("visited", "yes");
            _this.addContent();
        }
    };

    _this.addContent = function() {
        var newContent = $(document.createElement("div")).html("<p>This is the content you've been waiting for.</p>");
        $("#content").empty().append(newContent);
    };

    return _this;
};

var CookieManager = function() {
    _this = this;

    _this.setCookie = function(cookieKey, cookieValue) {
        var cookieStr = cookieKey+"="+cookieValue;
        document.cookie = cookieStr;
    };

    _this.getCookie = function(cookieKey) {
        var regex = new RegExp(cookieKey+"\=([^;]+)");
        var cookie = document.cookie.match(regex);
        if(cookie !== null) {
            return cookie[1];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };

    _this.deleteCookie = function(cookieKey) {
        document.cookie = cookieKey+"=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    };

    return _this;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what i'm looking for,but i am unable  due to lack of knowledge how to optimize with my needed thing.
In the first Welcome, first-timer i need to add the countdown and a image ads ,after it with jquery to be shown the content,after another refresh or visit it should direct to the right Welcome Back! You've been here before ,i tried with include option for javascript and then adding the whole needed content but it failed.
Only alert and text works.
is there any way?
Thanks again

Comment: @Joel I updated the description and example code to do what you're asking

Comment: This is what the exact thing im looking ,i'm trying with wordpress but the countdown does not get to work,i am pasting over the post section,so do you think i need to add at the single-post? If you have experience on wordpress.

Comment: @Joel That seems like a different question. If this answers your first question, could you please mark it as the answer?

Comment: Yes,apologies for it.
This is the exact copy/ of what i was looking at. :) Thanks for ur time

Comment: Friend,is there any way to make the This is the content you've been waiting for on div ? because i will integrate with wordpress with other  messages other then This is the content you've been waiting for  ?
regards